# Can't check if recording was successful after maxRecordedDuration expires

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I am trying to make an app which can record video to the file. I used this documentation file as the guide: [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2). The problem appears when video duration reaches it's maximum allowed duration. This is how i set max duration:

```
    self.avOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];
    self.avOutput.maxRecordedDuration = CMTimeMake(5 * 20, 20);
```

Then this method is called and that's where trouble begins:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput
    didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL
    fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections
    error:(NSError *)error 
{
    BOOL recordedSuccessfully = YES;
    if ([error code] != noErr) {
        // A problem occurred: Find out if the recording was successful.
        id value = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey];
        if (value) {
            recordedSuccessfully = [value boolValue];
        }
    }

    // some code...

}
```

So, this method call:`[[error userInfo] objectForKey:AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey]` returns `nil` as a result and I can't check if recording is finished regularly.

It's very strange, because i didn't find any part of documentation that covers this particular case.
This is what I get when error log is printed:

```
(lldb) po error
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11810 "Recording Stopped" UserInfo=0x146443c0 {AVErrorTimeKey=CMTime: {100/20 = 5.000}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The recording reached the maximum allowable length., NSLocalizedDescription=Recording Stopped, NSUnderlyingError=0x1463edb0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -16132.)"}

(lldb) po error.userInfo
{
    AVErrorTimeKey = "CMTime: {100/20 = 5.000}";
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Recording Stopped";
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "The recording reached the maximum allowable length.";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16132 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (OSStatus error -16132.)\"";
}
```

Can someone help me to overcome this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm not sure if you ever found a solution to this problem but I go about this by checking for the size of the recorded video as follows, using

```
    @property(nonatomic, strong) NSData *getVideo;
```

as follows:

```
    //At the end of the method above add:

    getVideo = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:outputFileURL];
    NSLog(@" size of getVideo %lu in bytes", (unsigned long)getVideo.length);
```

This will check for the size of the recorded video. I hope this was helpful. Did you find a better way to go about this question? Thanks!